# Azure Rate Card reserved instance pricing

Tags: azure

Is there an API provided by Azure providing information about Azure Rate Card pricing ?

The usual rate card doesn't seem to have any such information.

Comment: Any update this case?

Comment: Did you get a solution for it? I am also looking for a way to find prices of azure reserved instances through a restapi or java sdk.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Azure Billing APIs** to predict and manage your costs, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-usage-rate-card-overview).

> Use Azure Billing APIs to pull usage and resource data into your preferred data analysis tools. The Azure Resource Usage and RateCard APIs can help you accurately predict and manage your costs.

1. [Azure Invoice Download API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/): download invoices
2. [Azure Resource Usage API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/Mt219003.aspx): get your estimated Azure consumption data
3. [Azure Resource RateCard API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/Mt219005.aspx): get the list of available Azure resources and estimated pricing information for each

Comment: Sorry but they didn't serve my purpose. Microsoft provided us with a csv file with reserved instance pricing listed.